# Flask Proxy Server Error in HTTPS - Works in HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: python, flask, proxy

We have setup a basic proxy server on flask. It works fine in `HTTP` however when the request is made in `HTTPS` it throws up some issues that are proving difficult to debug.

It seems that the request is not correctly parsed by flask when in `HTTPS`.

A more detailed description is below

**Server Code**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from requests import exceptions


application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/",methods=["GET","POST","DELETE","PATCH","PUT"])
def route():
    try:
        response = requests.request(method=request.method, url=request.url, headers=request.headers,timeout=60)
        print(response.status_code, response.text)
        return (response.content, response.status_code, response.headers.items())
    except exceptions.ProxyError:
        return (b"Error", 408, request.headers.items())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=39100, debug=True, use_reloader=False,ssl_context=("certs/cert.pem","certs/key.pem"))
```

**Request Sample Code**

```
import requests

proxies = {"http":"https://127.0.0.1:39100", "https":"https://127.0.0.1:39100"}

# does not work if the request is http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
# works if the request is http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
testing = requests.get(url="https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/",proxies=proxies,verify=False) 
print(testing)
print(testing.content)
```

**Error**

```
/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/bin/python /Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/sudoRequest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 369, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 924, in _tunnel
    raise OSError(f"Tunnel connection failed: {code} {message.strip()}")
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 404 NOT FOUND

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipv4.icanhazip.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 404 NOT FOUND')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/sudoRequest.py", line 6, in <module>
    testing = requests.get(url="https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/",proxies=proxies,verify=False)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/PycharmProjects/invisiProxy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 559, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipv4.icanhazip.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 404 NOT FOUND')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: i think you need to set `debug=False` for https.

Answer (score 3):

Using `proxies` on `requests` for HTTPS causes client to use HTTP tunneling via `CONNECT` method. That is necessary for client to have direct TCP channel to the target in order to establish end-to-end encryption without any MITM proxy (see `urllib3` description for such case -- https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-usage.html#http-and-https-proxies).

The CONNECT method is not supported by your flask server hence it returns 404 on the request. The behavior can be observed on the MVP server provided:

```
# client request http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 12:08:12] "GET http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -

# client request https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 12:03:48] "CONNECT ipv4.icanhazip.com:443 HTTP/1.0" 404
```

Technically, expected behavior is possible to perform ...

```
# openssl s_client --connect 127.0.0.1:39100
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = xxxx
   i:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = xxxx
---
read R BLOCK
GET https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv4.icanhazip.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.1.2 Python/3.7.3
...

IP_REDACTED
read:errno=0
```

... and such case is documented and "tweakable" on `urllib3` level (used by `requests` for actual connections) with `use_forwarding_for_https` of
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.poolmanager.html#urllib3.ProxyManager

BUT

- such usage is not generally recommended, because it violates the design of TLS itself (end-to-end encryption between client and resource).
- in current `requests` implementation there seem to be NO way to pass required flag from the developer via standard api. `get_connection` function would not allow to pass any additional `proxy_kwargs` to `urllib3.ProxyManager`

```py
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/da9996fe4dc63356e9467d0a5e10df3d89a8528e/requests/adapters.py#L352

    def get_connection(self, url, proxies=None):
        ...
        if proxies:
            ...
            proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
            conn = proxy_manager.connection_from_url(url)


https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/da9996fe4dc63356e9467d0a5e10df3d89a8528e/requests/adapters.py#L201
    def proxy_manager_for(self, proxy, **proxy_kwargs):
        ...
        manager = self.proxy_manager[proxy] = proxy_from_url(
                ...
                **proxy_kwargs,
            )
```

I would recommend to use full-flegged http proxy instead of flask server.